# iFrame click events not working for browsers in iPhone (6/7/8)

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, google-chrome, iframe

We are creating a popup to ask for a website related question which pops up when the user is browsing the website. It is a
floating div containing an iFrame content. The problem is : when we click inside the iFrame content we are not able to get any
event for iPhones, majorly 6,7 and 8.

Note: iFrame source is not of the same domain as parent website.

Here is what I have used
...

```
<script>
$(document).click(function(){
    alert("clicked within iFrame content");
});
</script>
```

...

Here are some of the issues that are similar in nature that I have found.

https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/window/details/button-inside-an-iframe-or-radwindow-is-unclickable-on-ios-devices

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/28656

Help will be appreciated.